# How can I make a zoomed in copy of a photo and save it on my Nikon SLR?

Tags: nikon, cropping, in-camera-processing

Nikon d3200 - i am a beginner using this.  I took a picture and then when reviewing the playback I hit the zoom in button.  I would like to save a copy of this zoomed in photo on my camera.  How do I do this.  I have a camera that wasn't a DSLR and it did this.  The trim option on the button does not zoom in close enough.  And why can you only trim once?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not crop on your computer?

Comment: It just was easier to already have the photo cropped and use it that way.

Comment: Just curious of why my P&S allow me to do this but not a DSLR?

Answer (score 4):

With the current firmware of the D3200 you can't crop the image arbitrarily, you can however trim to the aspects (3:2, 4:3, 5:4, 16:9 and 1:1). This can only be done to sizes in certain steps only. You can access this function through the retouch menu and then jump to the function "Trim".

I would strongly advise against using this method to crop the photo. You have very limited control in what you do compared to performing the operation in the computer later on. If you want to use Nikon's own tools, you can use ViewNX 2 that comes bundled with the camera to perform this operation.

Nikon has more information about the Retouch menu and the trim function [here](http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d3200/features06.htm).